# Como leer una cadena de un fichero caracter por caracter y almacenarlo dentro de un vector c++

Tags: c++, array

Hola a todos mi problema es que tengo una cadena de este estilo. Cada vez que ejecuto mi programa la cadena cambia pues es aleatoria.

CGGACCCGTGGTCCGAGGTCTAAAGTGATTAGAAGCCGGT

La cuestión es que la debo ir leyendo caracter por caracter de ida y vuelta pero al momento de leer 4 caracteres almacenarlos para luego trabajar con las cadenas almacenadas. El problema es que al leer 4 caracteres por ejemplo CGGA no salto directamente a los otros 4 sino que leo los 4 siguientes GGAC para almacenarlos y así sucesivamente. Para posteriormente ordenarlos por numero de repeticiones.

Mi iterador se debe mover de 1 en 1 cuando lea 4 caracteres almacenar esa cadena, asi a lo largo de toda la cadena. Por ejemplo teniendo ACGTAGTCATGC. La primera cadena que almacenaria seria ACGT la segunda CGTA, la tercera GTAG, la cuarta TAGT la quinta AGTC asi con toda la cadena

Espero alguien me de una pista. Se los agradecería.

Comment: Podrias indicar la salida deseada para el ejemplo que muestras.

Comment: No he entendido absolutamente nada de tu pregunta. ¿Quieres leer de uno en uno? ¿De cuatro en cuatro? ¿Quieres leerlo todo y contar repeticiones?

Comment: mi iterador se debe mover de 1 en 1 cuando lea 4 caracteres almacenar esa cadena,  asi a lo largo de toda la cadena. Por ejemplo teniendo ACGTAGTCATGC. La primera cadena que almacenaria seria ACGT la segunda CGTA, la tercera GTAG, la cuarta TAGT la quinta AGTC   asi con toda la cadena

Comment: Los detalles que aclaran la pregunta deben ser una edición de la pregunta no un comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Si **siempre** vas a leer de cuatro en cuatro, puedes usar [`ifstream::read`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read):

> `basic_istream& read( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );`
>
> Extrae caracteres y los almacena en la memoria anexa del arreglo de caracteres cuyo primer elemento está apuntado por `s`. Los caracteres se extraen y almacenan hasta que cualquiera de estas condiciones ocurre:
>
> - `count` caracteres se han extraído y guardado.
> - Se encuentra el final del archivo (en cuyo caso, se llamará `setstate(failbit|eofbit)`). El número de caracteres que se pudieron extraer puede ser consultado usando `gcount()`.

Esta podría ser una manera de hacerlo:

```
std::vector<std::string> cuartetos;
char cuarteto[4]{};

if (std::ifstream datos{"datos.adn"})
{
    while (datos.read(cuarteto, 4))
        cuartetos.push_back(cuarteto);
}
```